# Interleave search results based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, random

I am working on a job search engine. The database consists of many jobs. I get 10 most recently updated jobs and display it on the first page. But I update the database with a few companies at a time and therefore all the results come out to be of the same company. Is there any way to write a query so that I can get jobs interleaved by different companies in batches of 10?

Distinct does not work as it removes all the jobs of the same company

For Example

If I have a list of

[image]

then the output of 5 jobs should be

[image]

Comment: sample table and expected output will be great...

Comment: Is it bad that I'm a native English speaker and I had to Google the definition of *interleave*?  It's paging...  Just say you want to page the results...

Comment: Is a random arrangement ok, or is the interleaving important?

Comment: @Siyual OP wants, I think, the result set displayed on each page to have a variety of companies, so it's more complicated than just paging.  We'll have to see what the sample tables/output look like to be sure.

Comment: @siyual, excatly I want each page to display variety of companies. Any inputs wuld be great.